# Recursive Poly1 to recurse over type parameters

Tags: scala, recursion, shapeless

I am using a `Poly1` from shapeless to build schemes of case classes(describing their serialization) from instances. To build a `Schema` of

```
case class A(b: B, c: String, d: List[Int], e: Option[List[Option[Int]]])
```

there needs to be a schema for every contained type.

A `Schema` object holds (besides other things) an example value for its members. I pull these example values from the instance for all *primitive* types (`Int`, `Float`, `String`, ...) whose schemes get constructed on the fly by my `Poly1`. All *complex* types (by that I mean custom types with other member values) get referenced instead, as they might have custom serialization methods as well. This is easily solved by requiring a schema to be present in the implicit scope.

Now it is known how to construct a `Schema` for any list (or any other collection) **iff** there is a `Schema` for the type parameter(s). This is the same for other monad-types like `Option`.

The idea of the `Poly1` is to map the member types to their schemes which get either constructed on the fly or looked up from the implicit scope. This requires me to define a case for all primitive types as well as all necessary monads. This approach generally works, but has a lot of boilerplate.

Current `Poly1` object (`NGSchema` is a `trait` which all `Schema[T]` instances inherit, `ref[T]` looks up an instance of `Schema[T]` from the implicit scope and the functions `integer`, `long` and `float` construct a `Schema[T]` with a given example):

```
private object typeRecursion extends Poly1 {
    implicit val caseInt      = at[Int]     [NGSchema](integer(_))
    implicit val caseLong     = at[Long]    [NGSchema](long(_))
    implicit val caseFloat    = at[Float]   [NGSchema](float(_))

    ...

    implicit def caseOption[T: Schema](implicit c: Case.Aux[T, NGSchema]) = at[Option[T]][NGSchema]{
      case Some(v) => OptionSchema(typeRecursion(v)(c))
      case None => OptionSchema(ref[T])
    }
    implicit def caseList[T: Schema](implicit c: Case.Aux[T, NGSchema]) = at[List[T]][NGSchema]{
      case v :: tl => SeqSchema(typeRecursion(v)(c))
      case Nil => SeqSchema(ref[T])
    }

    ...

    implicit def caseElse[T: Schema] = at[T][NGSchema]{
      case _ => ref[T]
    }
  }
```

This fails however in the case of the member `e` because the schema for `Option[List[Option[Int]]]` will not be present in the implicit scope as it should be constructed on the fly. I believe my `Poly1` should be recursive to solve this issue nicely. This however leaves the problem that the `Option` case does need some kind of Type-Bound for the inner most type which is unknown at that point in the recursion **iff** this is a complex type as this cant be constructed on the fly.

I would expect that the fuction would map `Option[List[Option[Int]]]` to `OptionSchema(SeqSchema(OptionSchema(integer(example))` while `Option[B]` should lookup `Schema[B]` from implicit scope and execute `OptionSchema(ref[B])`.

Is this even the right approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Poly1` itself isn't `implicit`, only the cases are implicit. I think you're confusing the typeclass level and the value level. I would separate the provision of the implicit `Schema` instances from the function that actually operates on them (which can probably just be an ordinary function?):

```
implicit object IntSchema extends NGSchema[Int]{ ... }
implicit def optionSchema[T: Schema] = new Schema[Option[T]]{...}
...
def myFunction[T: Schema](t: T) = ... //or Poly with cases here if you need it.
```

Comment: Wow... Sometimes things are much easier than they seem... Thank you very much.